# Can you change what a symlink points to after it is created?

Tags: unix, symlink

Does any operating system provide a mechanism (system call — not command line program) to change the pathname referenced by a symbolic link (symlink) — other than by unlinking the old one and creating a new one?

The [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard does not.  [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) 10 does not.  [Mac OS X 10.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard) does not. (I'm tolerably certain neither [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX) nor [HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX) does either. Judging from this list of [Linux system calls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/), Linux does not have such a system call either.)

Is there anything that does?

(I'm expecting that the answer is "No".)

---

Since proving a negative is hard, let's reorganize the question.

If you know that some (Unix-like) operating system not already listed has no system call for rewriting the value of a symlink (the string returned by `readlink()`) without removing the old symlink and creating a new one, please add it — or them — in an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with simply relinking?  Why not just issue the `ln` command (or the API equiavalent) overwriting the old link?  What problem are you having?

Comment: Funny - I'm asking whether there is a system call to do a programming job, and the question is being marked 'belongs on other site'.

Comment: Funny- It was absolutely not clear you were looking for a system call and you just edited the question to add this detail. So how can you  expect people to deduct something before you even write it?

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm writing up a paper on security and symbolic links.  At one point I make the assertion "the actual owner, group, permissions on the symlink itself are immaterial" and the reasoning is that the owner of the symlink can only remove it and not change the value.  I'm double checking that there is no way other than by removing the symlink of achieving the effect of 'rewriting the symlink value'.  I'm ignoring direct access to the raw disk and hacking the FS that way - it requires root privilege and my concerns are with non-root users, not with what root can do.

Comment: @Pascal: I'm sorry - I didn't realize it wasn't clear that I was talking about system calls until people went off on a tangent from what I intended (which was evidently different from what I said). I'm sorry to have misled; it was unintentional.

Comment: Another way to do it is to create a new symbolic link and then rename() it (it will replace the old one).

Comment: @martinkunev That's not actually editing it.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Actually, you can overwrite a symlink and thus update the pathname referenced by it:

```
$ ln -s .bashrc test
$ ls -al test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pascal pascal 7 2009-09-23 17:12 test -> .bashrc
$ ln -s .profile test
ln: creating symbolic link `test': File exists
$ ln -s -f .profile test
$ ls -al test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pascal pascal 8 2009-09-23 17:12 test -> .profile
```

As the OP pointed out in a comment, using the `--force` option will make `ln` perform a system call to `unlink()` before `symlink()`. Below, the output of `strace` on my linux box proving it:

```
$ strace -o /tmp/output.txt ln -s -f .bash_aliases test
$ grep -C3 ^unlink /tmp/output.txt
lstat64("test", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
stat64(".bash_aliases", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2043, ...}) = 0
symlink(".bash_aliases", "test")        = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
unlink("test")                          = 0
symlink(".bash_aliases", "test")        = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
```

The following is copied from [Arto Bendiken's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6786/245955) over on unix.stackexchange.com, circa 2016.

This **can** indeed be done atomically with `rename(2)`, by first creating the new symlink under a temporary name and then cleanly overwriting the old symlink in one go. As the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename) states:

> If *newpath* refers to a symbolic link the link will be overwritten.

In the shell, you would do this with `mv -T` as follows:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ ln -s a z
$ ln -s b z.new
$ mv -T z.new z
```

You can `strace` that last command to make sure it is indeed using `rename(2)` under the hood:

```
$ strace mv -T z.new z
lstat64("z.new", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=1, ...}) = 0
lstat64("z", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=1, ...}) = 0
rename("z.new", "z")                    = 0
```

Note that in the above, both `mv -T` and `strace` are Linux-specific.

On FreeBSD, use `mv -h` alternately.

This is how Capistrano has done it for years now, ever since ~2.15. See [this pull request](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/460/files#r3969949).

Comment: Doesn't the '-f' option force 'ln' to do the unlink() then symlink() system calls?

Comment: It does. But the question might have been perceived as "how do I do that in one step" and then it boils down to the definition of "step" -  command line? syscall?

Comment: I've just noticed that you added syscall wording to your question ;-)

Comment: About the `--force` option, the man says "*remove existing destination files*". I don't know if this implies a call to unlink().

Comment: @Pascal: it does.  On Solaris, the output from 'truss ln -s p x' and 'truss ln -s -f p x' shows an unlink() call before the symlink() call in the second case (and a failed symlink() call in the first).  I would expect that to apply to most if not all variants of Unix.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson not to bring this back from the dead but that won't work (at least on Linux) if you the destination file is an existing symlink.  The symlink will still point to the original file.  Very surprising to me.

Comment: +1 to @Taai comment - if dealing with a symlink which dereferences (points to) a directory, you need to specify "-n" to be sure this trick works.

Comment: could you clarify what the `-T` option does, just so it is easier to understand? (treats as file, not directory)

Comment: That document doesn't actually say that renaming a temporary symbolic link to another existing symbolic link will edit the symbolic link.

Answer (score 183):

Yes, you can!

```
ln -sfn source_file_or_directory_name softlink_name
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The `-f` option means 'remove the existing destination' before creating the new one.  So, this command achieves the result, but by doing `unlink(2)` followed by `symlink(2)`.  This is not what the original question was about.  Also note that the accepted answer and the next most voted answer both use `ln -sf` to do the job, but as the `strace` output shows, it does `unlink()` and `symlink()` because there isn't a system call to modify a symlink.

Comment: The -n seems to be required when the original link goes to a directory instead of a file.

Comment: The 'n' switch is important. I struggled with the problem that the symlink was not updated but the command created another link inside the existing one because the 'no derefencing' option was not set.

Comment: The -n option will make the action become atomic, there will be no unlink get called internally. I have confirmed this by strace, it actually do the `ln -s source a_tmp_file && mv -T a_tmp_file symlink`.

Answer (score 15):

It is not necessary to explicitly unlink the old symlink.  You can do this:

```
ln -s newtarget temp
mv temp mylink
```

(or use the equivalent symlink and rename calls).  This is better than explicitly unlinking because rename is atomic, so you can be assured that the link will always point to either the old or new target.  However this will not reuse the original inode.

On some filesystems, the target of the symlink is stored in the inode itself (in place of the block list) if it is short enough; this is determined at the time it is created.

Regarding the assertion that the actual owner and group are immaterial, [symlink(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/symlink.7.html) on Linux says that there is a case where it is significant:

> The owner and group  of  an  existing  symbolic  link  can  be changed  using
>   lchown(2).   The  only  time  that the ownership of a symbolic link matters is
>   when the link is being removed or renamed in a directory that has the sticky
>   bit set (see stat(2)).
>
> The  last  access  and  last modification timestamps of a symbolic link can be
>   changed using utimensat(2) or lutimes(3).
>
> On Linux, the permissions of a symbolic link are not used in any operations;
>   the  permissions  are always 0777 (read, write, and execute for all user
>   categories), and can't be changed.

Comment: @mark4o: The Good - The reference to lchown() and ownership in a sticky-it directory is useful - thanks.  I was aware of lchown() and it wasn't material to my thesis.  I was also aware of sticky-bit directories; I think that the ownership is almost a standard consequence of the rules - the difference, and presumably why it is called out, is that normally you can remove a file if you can write to it, and nominally, anyone can write to a symlink because of the 777 permissions, but in this case, the rules are slightly different.

Comment: @mark4o: The Not So Good - the command sequence shown doesn't do what you think it does (at least, in the scenario: `set -x -e;
mkdir junk;
(
cd junk;
mkdir olddir newdir;
ln -s olddir mylink;
ls -ilR;
ln -s newdir temp;
ls -ilR;
mv temp mylink;
ls -ilR;
);
rm -fr junk`).  If you create files oldfile and newfile instead of directories and run the equivalent script (mainly changing olddir to oldfile, newdir to newfile), then you get the effect you were expecting.  Just one extra complexity!  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 3):

Just a warning to the correct answers above:

Using the -f / --force Method provides a risk to lose the file if you mix up source and target:

```
mbucher@server2:~/test$ ls -la
total 11448
drwxr-xr-x  2 mbucher www-data    4096 May 25 15:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 mbucher www-data    4096 May 25 15:13 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mbucher www-data 4109466 May 25 15:26 data.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 mbucher www-data 7582480 May 25 15:27 otherdata.tar.gz
lrwxrwxrwx  1 mbucher www-data      11 May 25 15:26 thesymlink -> data.tar.gz
mbucher@server2:~/test$ 
mbucher@server2:~/test$ ln -s -f thesymlink otherdata.tar.gz 
mbucher@server2:~/test$ 
mbucher@server2:~/test$ ls -la
total 4028
drwxr-xr-x  2 mbucher www-data    4096 May 25 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 mbucher www-data    4096 May 25 15:13 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mbucher www-data 4109466 May 25 15:26 data.tar.gz
lrwxrwxrwx  1 mbucher www-data      10 May 25 15:28 otherdata.tar.gz -> thesymlink
lrwxrwxrwx  1 mbucher www-data      11 May 25 15:26 thesymlink -> data.tar.gz
```

Of course this is intended, but usually mistakes occur. So, deleting and rebuilding the symlink is a bit more work but also a bit saver:

```
mbucher@server2:~/test$ rm thesymlink && ln -s thesymlink otherdata.tar.gz 
ln: creating symbolic link `otherdata.tar.gz': File exists
```

which at least keeps my file.

Comment: Using a `-f` or `--force` option is always a bit dangerous; it presumes the user knows what they're about.  It is doubly lethal if you use it habitually (`rm -fr …` every time is dangerous).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't unlinking it and creating the new one do the same thing in the end anyway?

Comment: Why unlink in the first place?  Why not simple overwrite it?

Comment: The net result is approximately the same - but the owner and group and last modified times (and probably inode number) would all be different, in general.

Comment: @S.Lott: what system call does the 'overwrite'?  In POSIX, there is no such call.  In Solaris and MacOS X, there is no such call.  Is there a call to do that on ... Linux, AIX, HP-UX, anything else that looks like Unix?  Windows doesn't really have symlinks in the same way, AFAICT, so it is not critical to my analysis - but information about the equivalent Windows API would be useful.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Ummm.... the `ln --force` command will absolutely overwrite an existing link.

Comment: Guys, I think you are talking at cross purposes. S.Lott is discussing an executable `ln (1)`, while matt b. is discussing the fact that `symlink (2)` does *not* support overwriting. You are both right, and I would suggest that looking at the implementation of `ln (1)` would give the most idomatic way of accomplishing the unlink-relink procedure.

Comment: Actually I just didn't know that ln had a --force argument :(

Comment: Question marks do not belong in answers, even if rhetorical. Can you provide a more affirmative answer, please? But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps: there is a way to edit a symlink with midnight commander (mc).
The menu command is (in French on my mc interface):

```
Fichier / Éditer le lien symbolique
```

which may be translated to:

```
File / Edit symbolic link
```

The shortcut is C-x C-s

Maybe it internally uses the `ln --force` command, I don't know.

Now, I'm trying to find a way to edit a whole lot of symlinks at once (that's how I arrived here).

Comment: Have you verified what MC does behind the scenes?  I'd lay odds that in fact it does an `unlink()` followed by a `symlink()`, simply because that's what Unix-like systems provide.

Comment: No, I haven't checked. And yes, it is quite probable that it does as you say, in fact.The fact that I edit a textbox gives the feeling that I am actually editing the symlink target, but I've probably been fooled...

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there's no built-in command to edit an existing symbolic link. It can be easily achieved with a few short commands.

Here's a little **bash/zsh function** I wrote to update an existing symbolic link:

```
# -----------------------------------------
# Edit an existing symbolic link
#
# @1 = Name of symbolic link to edit
# @2 = Full destination path to update existing symlink with 
# -----------------------------------------
function edit-symlink () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Name of symbolic link you would like to edit:"
        read LINK
    else
        LINK="$1"
    fi
    LINKTMP="$LINK-tmp"
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "Full destination path to update existing symlink with:"
        read DEST
    else
        DEST="$2"
    fi
    ln -s $DEST $LINKTMP
    rm $LINK
    mv $LINKTMP $LINK
    printf "Updated $LINK to point to new destination -> $DEST"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. This doesn't meet my requirement of being a C language system call. There are numerous way to change a link as long as you have write permission on the directory holding the link (which this requires). There no ways that I know of, even now, to change the value of a symlink without doing `unlink()` and `symlink()` with the new value, which is what goes on behind the scenes with your code. Personally, I'd have the function insist on exactly two (or perhaps a multiple of two) arguments and bail if the invocation was not correct. That's a particular perspective, though.

Answer (score 0):

**You can modify the softlink created once in one of the  two ways as below in Linux**

1. one is where you can remove existing softlink with rm and again create new softlink with ln -s command .
2. However this can be done in one step , you can replace existing softlink with updated path  with "ln -vfns Source_path Destination_path" command.

**Listing initial all files in directory**

```
$ ls -lrt 
drwxrwxr-x. 3 root    root      110 Feb 27 18:58 test_script
$
```

**Create softlink test for test_script with ln -s command.**

```
$ ln -s test_script test
$ ls -lrt
drwxrwxr-x. 3 root    root      110 Feb 27 18:58 test_script
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root    root       11 Feb 27 18:58 test -> test_script
$
```

**Update softlink test with new directory test_script/softlink with single command**

```
$ ln -vfns test_script/softlink/ test
'test' -> 'test_script/softlink/'
$
```

**List new softlink location**

```
$ ls -lrt
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root    root       21 Feb 27 18:59 test -> test_script/softlink/
$
```

**ln --help**

-v, --verbose               print name of each linked file

-f, --force                 remove existing destination files

-n, --no-dereference        treat LINK_NAME as a normal file if it is a symbol

-s, --symbolic              make symbolic links instead of hard links

Comment: Thank you, but the question says _"Does any operating system provide a mechanism (system call — not command line program) …"_. What you describe are command-line programs doing the job, and AFAICT they are simply using the `unlink()` and `symlink()` system calls, not some hypothetical 'altersymlink()` system call.